# Entering cheats for Just Dance 3 on Playstation Move?

Tags: ps3, playstation-move, just-dance-3

How do I enter the cheat code on Just Dance 3 for Playstation Move if there are no buttons that can be used to enter the code?

Comment: Have you tried using a DualShock controller to enter them?

Comment: It doesn't work but if I tried again what buttons should I use

Comment: And what is the title screen I'm supposed to go to To do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a **PS Move Navigation Controller** if the DualShock isn't working (although I can't imagine why it wouldn't work)

The title screen will be the very first screen you come to after calibrating the Move controllers - the one with the title 'Just Dance 3'. If you still can't find it, it also says "Press *Move* to Continue". If it doesn't work on that screen try it on the main menu which has the 'Dance' and 'Just Sweat' options etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What buttons if any would I use to put in the code on the move remote

Comment: @Elizabeth Glad I could help :) I'm not quite sure what you mean in terms of which buttons. You would use the ones the cheat codes says to use. On the D-Pad of the Navigation controller for the ` Extreme Choreography` cheat.